# How to control IE Explorer with pywinauto

Tags: python, internet-explorer, pywinauto

Ok, so I want to control a IE Explorer with pywinauto. I would like to select text fields on the page and edit them. Is there a way to do this with pywinauto without clicking where the text field are? The pages will be the same every time, but not the data that is entered into them. The window may not be in the same place every time, so I couldn't do **WrapperObject.Click(coords=fixed_pos)**. Sample code is preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You can control the window of IE, all the toolbars and buttons, address bar and search bar, etc. But not content of pages within.

For this task, you need other tools, such as Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/

As for pywinauto,I strongly recommend to use the utility SWAPY http://code.google.com/p/swapy/. I am the Author of SWAPY. With it you can easily determine whether it is possible to manage the a control with pywinauto or not.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with this project in your answers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - To be fair, all of them were posted in a span of a few minutes today, so they may not have gotten the message on this yet. I'll give the benefit of the doubt to someone promoting an open source project, but I've warned them and removed the clearly mistargeted answers.