# How to control and interact with elements on a webpage displayed with IE or a different browser with pywinauto

Tags: python, html, pywinauto

I want to be able to access the elements of a webpage with python. I use Python 2.5 with Windows XP. Currently, I am using pywinauto to try to control IE, but I could switch to a different browser or module if it is needed. I need to be able to click the buttons the page has and type in text boxes. So far the best I've gotten is I was able to bring IE to the page I wanted. If it is possible without actually clicking the coords of the buttons and text boxes on the page, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773356/how-to-control-ie-explorer-with-pywinauto

Answer (score 2):

I think for interacting with webserver better is to use cUrl. All webservers function are responses for GET or POST request (or both). in order to call them, just call the urls that buttons are linked to and/or send POST data attaching that data to appropiate request obj before calling send method. cUrl is able to retrieve and do some processing on webserver responce (web site code) without displaying it, what delivers knowledge about  url adresses contained in the web site, which are called when clicking certain buttons. Also possible to know html fields which carry POST data to get their names.
Python has curl lib, which I hope is so powerful as PHP curl, tool what I used and presented.

Hope you are on the track now.

BR
Marek

Comment: Not really what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Tommy ,
What i Have observer till now if u have a web application and if u are able to identify the object in that page using winspy (tool for spyup the controls in the page). you can automate that. Else you cant.

Like using following code

```
app = Application.Application();
app.window_(title_re = 'Internet Explorer. *').OKButton.Click()
```