# Selenium is not able to handle pop up window or alert in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, popupwindow

I want to get the text of the pop up window in the attached image. Right now I am using selenium in python for getting those text value. Following is my code-

```
time.sleep(LOADING_TIME)
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
print(alert.text())
```

But, when I am doing that I am getting following error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Note that: I am using chrome driver for initializing selenium driver and the example I have added here can be found whenever you want to add an extension to your chrome browser.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `driver.switch_to.alert` is a function.

Change it like so:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(your_url)

alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()

# Eventually do anything else.

driver.close()
```

[EDIT]

Since it seems that selenium doesn't recognize the dialog, you could use [pywinauto module](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html): to get the dialog and interact with it.

```py
from pywinauto import Application


driver_handle = driver.current_window_handle  # get driver window handle
app = Application().connect(handle = driver_handle)  # initialize app

dialog = pywinauto.app.top_window_()  # select the dialog

dlg.control.Addextension.Click()  # click on "Add extension" button
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.
I have a concern about your suggestion. I believe the driver and browser is the same instance here?

Comment: can you please confirm me whether the pop up dialog is an alert or something else? I am guessing it is not an alert that's why selenium is not able to detect it as an alert dialog.

Comment: In such cases, the solution is to use pywinauto module, because there may be no way to handle the dialog.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903085/1804054 

in this post one mentioned that it will not be possible to control the page content using pywinauto module. Can you explain a bit more what approaches are you thinking in terms of getting the dialog content using pywinauto? 
Have you ever tried this in crawling website?

Comment: thanks for your effort. But when I run this code I got an error 

ImportError: No module named 'win32process'

May be this error is causing because I am using Mac. Not Sure though.